# Why does assignment operator call both copy ctor and assignment operator?

Tags: c++, oop

Here is my code which I expect to output "Assignment" but getting both "copy" and "Assignment ".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    Test(){}
    Test(Test &t){ cout<<"\n copy ";}
    void operator = (Test t) {cout<<"\n Assignment ";}
};

void main()
{
Test t1;    //default ctor
Test t3;
t3=t1;    //Assignment 
}
```

If I change my code to

```
void operator = (Test &t) {cout<<"\n Assignment ";}
```

I get expected ouput only "Assignment".

What is the difference in both?

Comment: In your case your assignment operator takes parameter by copy(copy constr called).But if you changed it to take by reference it will not called.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that the argument `Test t` passes `t` *by value*.  That invokes the copy constructor to create a separate local copy that you can use within the function.

When you use `Test &t` (note that it *should* have been `const Test &t`), you are passing a reference to the original value, thus avoiding copying.

Notes:

- the *correct* signature of an assignment operator is this (satisfy the return value by `return *this;`):

  ```
  Test & operator = (const Test &t);
  ```
- the *correct* signature for copy constructor is this:

  ```
  Test(const Test &t);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
void operator=(Test t) { ... }
```

Expects the argument by value. The argument `t` is constructed by using the copy constructor.

```
void operator=(Test& t) { ... }
```

expects the argument by reference. The reference is an alias to the object used to call the function. Hence, it does not create a new object.

Answer (score 1):

When you do following:

```
operator = (Test t)
```

compiler makes a **copy** of t1 to create t3....

you mean passing a reference of Test instead of a copy....

do

```
void operator = (Test& t) { cout << "\n Assignment "; }
```

instead of

```
void operator = (Test t) { cout << "\n Assignment "; }
```